# Is there an alternative to grc (CLI output colorizer) for Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, color

I'm wondering if there's any Windows CLI tool that can easily colorize popular command output, such as log file contents and some commonly used CLI commands like ping. I'm looking for something that's more or less actively developed. The closest I've found is ColorCat: https://github.com/MasterDevs/ColorCat but its last commits were 8 years ago. I'll add also that it should be free and preferably open source.

Any other proposals?